# How can I prevent two users from accessing MySQL table at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I got a website which, when visited, shows what is your lucky word today. The problem is that every word can be lucky for only one person so you need to be fast visiting the website. Below is a sample table with lucky words:

```
+---------------------+
| lucky_word          |
+---------------------+
| cat                 |
| moon                |
| piano               |
| yellow              |
| money               |
+---------------------+
```

My question is: how can I prevent two (or more) users from accessing that table at one time. I assume that every user reads the first *lucky_word* from the existing table and the chosen word is deleted immediately so it won't be the next user's lucky word. For instance, I want to avoid *cat* to be shown to more than one visitor.

Should I solve this using an appropriate MySQL query or some lines in a PHP code or both?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: @BK435 I'm using innodb. Kenan, thank you for the link, I'll look at that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) within a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html); for example, using PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8;dbname='.DBNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

$pdo->beginTransaction();

$word = $pdo->query('SELECT lucky_word FROM myTable LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE')
            ->fetchColumn();

$pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM myTable WHERE lucky_word = ?')
    ->execute(array($word));

$pdo->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can *lock* tables, to prevent other sessions reading and/or writing to the table. In the case of WRITE locks, the first session to request the lock will hold the table until it is released, and then the second session will get it until unlocked, and so forth. That way you can be sure that no two sessions are accessing or manipulating the same data at the same time.

Read all about it in the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: The problem with this approach is that *the entire table* is locked against any activity by other connections until the lock is released.  This can very rapidly lead to applications becoming unusable.  Row-level locking, as provided for by transactional storage engines like InnoDB, is a far better approach.

Comment: @eggyal True; if available, row locking is the better solution. - Perhaps it's fair to assume that InnoDB is being used at this point? I'm not sure. Without knowing the engine being used, though, table locking would be the ubiquitous solution.

Comment: [It is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290043/how-can-i-prevent-two-users-from-accessing-mysql-table-at-the-same-time/29290184?noredirect=1#comment46777551_29290043).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a datestamp to the table updated when that particular word is used?

You could then use the following pseudo sql...

```
select word from words where lastdate <> [today];
update words set lastdate = today where word = [word];
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the concurrency issue. Theoretically, given enough traffic (or exceptionally bad timing), another session could issue a select in between this session's select and update, thus fetching the same word for two different sessions. You need to obtain a lock to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

A quickly method I used for a similar task:

1) create a table "unique_sequence" with just un field: id -> INT AUTOINCREMENT

```
 CREATE TABLE `erd`.`unique_sequence` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

2) when a user arrives on the site:

```
INSERT INTO unique_sequence VALUES();
SELECT word FROM lucky_word WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

As The ID that was generated by LAST_INSERT_ID() is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis it should be multi-user safe...

... and so we can be sure that every new user will get a unique ID that match the ones in lucky_word table.